# Android deployed App unable to instantiate application

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I have this strange error I do not know how to resolve. 
I test my App deployed straight to my phone and it's working ok. But now testing downloading from Play Store the app crash as startup and the error is this one:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.bookit.android.BookItApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.bookit.android.BookItApp

I have this class:

```
package com.bookit.android;

public class BookItApp extends Application {...}
```

My manifest I think it's ok defining the App class:

> < application
>           android:name="BookItApp"

Or Maybe should I define:

> android:name = "com.bookit.android.BookItApp"

**UPDATE:**
this is my proguard-project.txt

I don't know if it's ok.

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
```

Comment: that can be proguard issue. was proguar enabled at project.properties file? if so do you have -keep public class * extends android.app.Application at your proguard conf file?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like you said, you should define it like this

```
<application 
           android:name="com.bookit.android.BookItApp"
           ...
           ...
           >
```

Comment: I have upload a new apk to Play Store with the modification. Now I have to wait until Google refresh my app page with the updated one in order to check if it fix the problem

Comment: The app is updated and know it's working ok. So I think that was the real problem, because I did not make any other change.

Comment: This is amazing!!! Now the app suddenly stops working again. Now it has a whole new error "Unable to instantiate application com.bookit.android.BookItApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bookit.android.BookItApp" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.bookit.android-1.apk"

Answer (score 0):

The error says that “java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bookit.android.BookItApp”, so the definition is fine

You can unzip the apk to find  "com.bookit.android.BookItApp", if it's missing ,maybe caused by packging.

PS:Does it occurrs always？

Comment: Yes, always only when I deploy the App from the Play Store. If I do straight from my computer to phone, there is no problem. The unzipped package has a "classes.dex" I think have inside my BookItApp class but I do not know how to check for it...The other files are resources, libraries, etc..